# Downloading a file through a JS function with requests-html

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, download, python-requests-html

I am scraping a website where I need to download a file. The file is usually downloaded by clicking a button `Generate`, however looking into the source code it calls a JavaScript function that submits a form, it looks something like this:

```
function formFunc{
    // Declare a bunch of form values here
    document.frmCriterio.action = "main_xml.asp";
    document.frmCriterio.target = "_self";
    document.frmCriterio.submit();
    return true;
}
```

I tried to replicate the behavior by navigating to that page with python `requests-html` and using the render method to run that same function with my given parameters:

```
response.html.render(script=create_js(prov_id), cookies=cookies)
```

However when I try to do this I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\sears_mvp\sears_session.py", line 280, in <module>
    my_func(param)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\sears_mvp\sears_session.py", line 235, in my_func
    response.html.render(script=create_js(prov_id), cookies=cookies)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\sears_mvp\venv\Scripts\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 670, in render
    raise MaxRetries("Unable to render the page. Try increasing timeout")
requests_html.MaxRetries: Unable to render the page. Try increasing timeout
```

Even after changing the parameters for `timeout`, and `retries` as well as some others I still got the same error. I even tried changing the target for `document.frmCriterio.target` (see above), but to no avail.

I know the JS function itself is working because I have navigated to the site on Firefox, inserted the function via the console, called it from there and successfully downloaded the file. So the issue is with accessing it via `requests-html`.

So my question is what should I do to be able to download this file?

Whether it be to modify the JS function or to implement a solution in python in this module or another module or something completely different.

(PS: I want to avoid using `Selenium` at the moment, but I can migrate the project over the `Selenium` if I must.)

Comment: what do you have in `create_js(prov_id)` ?

Comment: as I know `requests_html` uses [pypetter](https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer) which is tool for test like `selenium` - so you want to avoid `selenium` but you already use tool similar to `selenium`

Comment: I format the above javascript function to the parameters I want as a string because requests-html uses js eval to run the function.

Comment: maybe you format wrong code and it can't execute it. Maybe you should display it `print( create_js(prov_id) )` and copy displayed text to browser to see if it works.

Comment: The issue with selenium is that its hard to run concurrently with other things, I am starting to look more into pyppeteer to see if I can get it working with it @furas

Comment: I have printed its output, I even printed the output and inserted it on the site withe the console and ran the function. When I did that it successfully downloaded the file, so yea :/

Comment: you would have to run selenium in separated thread, and if you have some problem with `selenium` then you may have the same problem  with `pyppeteer`. Here is source code for [requests_html](https://github.com/psf/requests-html/blob/master/requests_html.py) - maybe you find something interesting. Eventually you can find this source code on your computer `print( requests-html.__file__ )` and you may add some `print()` to see which part of this code makes problem.